# How to make an svc WCF service use AspNetSynchronizationContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, wcf, async-await

In an ASP.NET project (.NET 4.5) I have both Web Api controllers, and some .svc WCF services.

By default, the actions of the Web Api controllers are executed on the `AspNetSynchronizationContext`, but the WCF service is using the default `SynchronizationContext`. Because of this, **async-await** cannot be properly used in the WCF service, since I depend on `HttpContext.Current`.

I tried to add the `aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext` setting, and also the `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` tag to the web.config, but none of them helped.

What is the reason for this? Is it possible to us the `AspNetSynchronizationContext` in WCF services hosted in ASP.NET?

Comment: Just stumbled upon the very same issue in the code I review. My current recommendation is to not to use the async code in WCF. However, since I've found your old question, I am curious if you were able to find any solution for this? Regards.

Comment: Hi @WiktorZychla! No, I haven't found any solution, so in the end we stopped using `async` in our WCF service.

Comment: Thanks again. Due to significant amount of async code in lower layers, our final recommendation was to rewrite the REST WCF to WebAPI.